# How to get component link for internal/external/multimedia working

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Given this modelling part, relevant for the linking.

[image]

Component linking should be implement for linking to:

### 1. Inside website

Linking to e.g. article, article-top-tasks.
Created field with XML name "internalLink" for schema and model.
It works without Link (schema/model).  Why? I was suprised ;-)

### 2.Outsite website

Created schema "ExterneLink" (for reuse), it contains 1 field for Url.
To get this to work, schema and model defined, can us it value in class/view.
Advantage: Works. It's also normal for embedded of component linking.
Disadvantage: Extra field.

> Example for 1: Inside website 'Tegel' (Tile)

[image]

> Example for 2 extended for Outside website

[image]

#### Questions:

#### Q1-  Can you custom (extend/change) Link schema e.g. icon or drop altText?

Core example application use "Link" schema.
Sdl.Web.Common.Model.Link has model in Dxa Framework.
I made a Link model myself, when tested the Url is NOT resolved. Why?

#### Q2- Created schema/model "List item" instead of "Link".

Advantage and disadvantage?

#### Q3- Multimedia schema "Document" for upload/link "Pdf files".

Will it work with xml name "internalLink" (like inside website above)?

Comment: See PlantUML for modelling (like this drawing).

Comment: Supporting both internal and external links is quite common and can be implemented using a single View Model property. See https://docs.sdl.com/784837/557501/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/semantic-mapping---net-

Comment: Please clarify your requirements for using an embedded Schema/Model for the external link (and for changing the Link model).

Comment: Content Manager fields (1x CL [insite],1x url [outsite] and mapping to one field in model as string work. Discovered not restrited to xmlnames (internalLink,externalLink).
Can define Link but also as model Link? Requirements: 1. customable icon in view, can do it in Link schema? No AlternateText.
2. url [outsite] must be occurs once, and used in datamodel on different places (called ExterneLink).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, I don’t fully understand all of your questions nor requirements, but let me clarify some things:

- Semantic mapping does not presume any field names; field names are either derived from the View Model property names or explicitly specified in `[SemanticProperty]` annotations. So, your statement “other XML names than `internalLink` doesn’t work” is incorrect.
- The semantic mapping automatically resolves Component Links if you map a Component Link field to a property of type `String` or `Link` (in the latter case it also preserves the Component ID in `Link.Id`)
- A Component Link field can also be mapped to an embedded Entity Model (i.e. a property of type `EntityModel` or a subclass).

  - In this case, full semantic mapping is applied to the embedded Entity
    Model.
  - If this embedded Entity Model has a property of type `String`
    or `Link` annotated with `[SemanticProperty(“_self”)]`, you can also get the resolved link URL.
  - If the embedded Entity Model derives from `MediaItem` (which, in turn, derives from `EntityModel`) and the linked Component is a Multimedia Component, the Media Item’s URL (and other properties) will also be set.
  - The semantic mapping resolves the embedded Entity Model type from the linked Component’s Schema (through semantic type mappings and type registration). This is sometimes referred to as *polymorphic mapping*.

To fully understand how semantic mapping works, have a look at the [DefaultModelBuilder](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultModelBuilder.cs) implementation, in particular: the `MapXYZ` methods.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear up, flexible that type String or Link can be used. Removed Q4.